# Why doesn't Annie's Bear increase HP or damage on level up?

Tags: league-of-legends

It's been a while that Annie's Ultimate, summoning a bear, doesn't do what it is supposed to upon leveling up. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you saying the HP doesn't increase when *Annie* levels up, or when *Summon:Tibbers* is leveled up?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you mean its not leveling when you level the spell or what, but here is what's supposed to happen.  Every time you put a level in Summon: Tibbers he increases in HP, Damage and his Aura (not to mention cost to summon):

- Cost: 150 / 200 / 250 mana.
- Magic Damage: 200 / 325 / 450 (+0.7 per ability power)
- Tibber's Health: 1,200 / 1,600 / 2,000 health.
- Tibber's Damage: 80 / 105 / 130

Answer (score 1):

Changes to Tibbers as of League of Legends v1.0.0.140

- Cost: 125 / 175 / 225 mana
- Summon Magic Damage: 200 / 325 / 450 (+0.7 per ability power)
- Attack Damage: 85 / 105 / 130
- Health: 1200 / 1600 / 2000
- Armor: 30 / 50 / 70
- Magic Resist: 25 / 45 / 65